# Get type_info for subclass when using shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, polymorphism, shared-ptr, typeinfo

I have the following minimal example code. I want to be able to determine the Derived class in my `Application::HandleEvent` method.

The Application class will ultimately contain a `map` which maps `type_info` to a handler function (I know how to do this using `operator<`) to route Events to their specific handlers.

There is no issue doing this using polymorphism with raw pointers, but I'm unable to do this if `shared_ptr`s are brought into the mix.

It always reports that the type_info is that of the base class, whether I use type_info of the `shared_ptr` (not a big surprise the smart pointers are not polymorphically related) or `type_info` of the pointed to class using `.get()`.

Is this possible? I'm not looking for a solution whereby I define a handler method in the event subclass itself.

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

class Event
{
    public:
    virtual ~Event(){};
};

class SpecificEvent1 : public Event
{};

class SpecificEvent2 : public Event
{};

class Application
{
    public: 
    void HandleEvent(boost::shared_ptr<Event> e)
    {
        std::cout << typeid(e.get()).name() << "\n";
        std::cout << typeid(e).name() << "\n";
    }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    Application app;

    boost::shared_ptr<SpecificEvent1> se1 = boost::make_shared<SpecificEvent1>();
    boost::shared_ptr<SpecificEvent2> se2 = boost::make_shared<SpecificEvent2>();

    app.HandleEvent(se1);
    app.HandleEvent(se2);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `typeid` on a pointer, you get information about the pointer, not the underlying object. To get information about the underlying object corresponding to a polymorphic pointer, use a reference, i.e. dereference the pointer

Instead of

```
std::cout << typeid(e.get()).name() << "\n";
```

Use

```
std::cout << typeid(*e).name() << "\n";
```

Comment: Of course. I should be asking for type info of the type not the pointer.`std::cout << typeid(*e).name() << "\n";` also works.

Comment: @PaulRooney, and that too.

Comment: Consider the case that `e` is null, too. Maybe it's irrelevant due to the application logic, then the assertion inside its `operator*` is sufficient.

Comment: I think all the samples using .get() should be stripped (or at least moved to the bottom). Smart pointers are ... _smart_ _pointers_. Meaning they're still pointers so if you want to dereference it, just say `*p`. `get()` is a lowlevel backdoor and should only be used when absolutely required. Using `get()` you no longer _the smart_ of the pointer

Comment: You missed something, @sehe, and that is that `*e.get()` might cause a silent null-pointer dereference while `*e` won't. One more point to following your advise.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I didn't miss it. I thought it was obvious/implied in "not using the _smart_" :) You're right though, it's probably good to mention it another time